# How 'a href' file on localhost using Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, hyperlink, opera

I've got simple project created in NetBeans using Apache Tomcat on localhost.

I've got a piece of code:

```
<td style="text-align: center; "><a href="file:///c:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/test.xml">konfiguracja</a></td>
```

When I click on link tehe is no reaction. When I try to change // and \ there is an error that cannot find this file.

I use Opera

Any ideas?

Comment: If it would be that easy to get to a File on each and every computer, we would all have big problems. Your local HDD is fortunately not visible for the clients connecting to your server. You have to move the file inside your webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers disallow links from **http:** or **https:** to **file:** addresses. Opera didn't do this originally, but stupid demos saying "your browser is insecure, click here to see the site access your hard drive" would pop up and make users nervous for no reason, so blocking was better.